# Apply regex filter in GET reques use Java code, not SQL

Tags: java, regex, database

I have a goal - get filtered contacts from database use Java, but not use SQL. Two problems:

1. Heavy Java code for use Database.
2. > IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in the request target. The valid characters are defined in RFC 7230 and RFC 3986, because I need use symbols as ^, [, ] and other.

I can't use regex in SQL, in Java only.

Which best ways for resolve this issues? 
My code.

```
public class Contact {
    private int id;
    private String name;

    public Contact() {
    }

    public Contact(ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException {
        setId(resultSet.getInt(1));
        setName(resultSet.getString(2));
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Contact [Id=" + id + ", Name=" + name + "]";
    }
} 

public class ManagementLayer {
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(String.valueOf(ManagementLayer.class));

    private ManagementLayer() {
    }

    private static class ManagementHolder{
        static final ManagementLayer Instance = new ManagementLayer();
    }

    public static synchronized ManagementLayer getInstance() {
        return ManagementHolder.Instance;
    }

    public List<Contact> getFilteredContacts(String regex, Connection dbConnection)
            throws SQLException, PatternSyntaxException {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        List<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<>();
        Statement statement = null;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;
        if (dbConnection == null) {
            try {
                Context context = new InitialContext();
                DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) context.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/hello");
                dbConnection = dataSource.getConnection();
            } catch (NamingException e) {
                LOG.info(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        try {
            if (dbConnection != null) {
                statement = dbConnection.createStatement();
                statement.setFetchSize(1);
                resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM contacts");
                while (resultSet.next()) {
                    String contactNameString = resultSet.getString(2);
                    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(contactNameString);
                    if (!matcher.matches()) {
                        Contact contact = new Contact();
                        contact.setId(resultSet.getInt(1));
                        contact.setName(contactNameString);
                        contacts.add(contact);
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println(contacts.toString());
        } finally {
            if (resultSet != null) {
                resultSet.close();
            }
            if (statement != null) {
                statement.close();
            }
        }
        return contacts;
    }
}


@Path("contacts")
public class WebServiceLayer {
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(String.valueOf(WebServiceLayer.class));

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<Contact> getNameFilter(@QueryParam("nameFilter") String val) {
        if (val == null || val.isEmpty()) {
            throw new WebApplicationException(Response
                    .status(HttpURLConnection.HTTP_BAD_REQUEST)
                    .entity("Error! Parameter is wrong or empty!")
                    .build());
        } else {
            List<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<>();
            try {
                contacts = ManagementLayer
                        .getInstance()
                        .getFilteredContacts(val, null);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                LOG.info(e.getMessage());
            }
            return contacts;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to encoding my reguest before sending. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

1. I used ConcurrentHashMap for create cache from database.
2. In Tomcat server.xml file added configuration (port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" URIEncoding="UTF-8" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443" relaxedQueryChars='^{}[]|$*'). Also in servlet added URLDecoder.decode(val) for resolving correct converting encoded symbols in regular expression.